# Call to a member function login() on a non-objectというエラー

Tags: php, cakephp

下記のソースの通りシンプルなログイン処理の実装を行ったのですがログインボタンを押した後、「Call to a member function login() on a non-object」というエラーが画面に表示されます。AppControllerにAuthのコンポーネントを読み込んでいるのでUsersControllerではAuthのコンポーネントを読みこまなくても良いと思っているのですがUsersControllerでもAuthを読み込む(public $components = array('Auth'))と記載しなければいけないのでしょうか。
※cakephp2で実装しています。

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    // アプリケーション全体にAuthコンポーネントを適用
    public $components = array('Auth','Session');
}

class UsersController extends Controller {

    public function login() {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(
                    'test error'
                );
            }
        }
    }
    public function logout() {
        $this->Auth->logout();
        return $this->redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: エラーメッセージから判断すると　$this->Auth->login()　の　$this->Auth が正しく設定されていない（オブジェクトではない何かになっている）という事だと思います。　$this->Auth を設定している部分のコードを質問に追加してください。

Comment: 自分自身で$this->Authに対して設定している箇所はない認識です。Cakephp2の場合、$this->Auth で正しく設定されるように何かコードを記載しなければならないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UsersControllerのextendsが「Controller」になっているのが原因でした。AppControllerに修正したらうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。